# String wasn't recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am getting an error when trying to parse a string to datetime.
I have tried this:

```
string x = "31/5/2012";   
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

and

```
string x = "31/5/2012";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

and

```
string x = "31/5/2012";  
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/MM/yyyy", cultureinfo.invariantculture));
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/M/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Since your string date has month as `5` not `05`, use single `M`

Comment: Supposing it was necessary to parse `1/1/2001` and `31/12/2001` as well as `31/5/2001`, is there a single string (perhaps `"d/M/yyyy"`) that will recognize all these?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `"d/M/yyyy"` will work for both `1/1/2001` and `31/12/2001`

Answer (score 0):

```
        string x = "31/5/2012";

        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/M/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Same question for you: Supposing it was necessary to parse `1/1/2001` and `31/12/2001` as well as `31/5/2001`, is there a single string (perhaps `"d/M/yyyy"`) that will recognize all these?